# How to set Onclicklistener for actions in snackbar android?

Tags: android, listener, snackbar

I am trying to set actions in a snackbar. I have the following code:

```
Snackbar.make(cb,lvMain.getChildCount()+" hotspots selected.",Snackbar.LENGTH_INDEFINITE).setAction("COPY TO",mOnClickListener).setActionTextColor(Color.RED).show();
```

How do I declare the listener "mOnClickListener" for the action ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
Snackbar snackbar = Snackbar
        .make(cb,lvMain.getChildCount()+" hotspots selected.",Snackbar.LENGTH_INDEFINITE)
        .setAction("COPY TO", new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

            }
        });

snackbar.show();
```

Answer (score 0):

Declare `View.OnClickListener mOnClickListener;` as class variable in `Activity` like,

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    View.OnClickListener mOnClickListener;
   // extra codes
}
```

then you can simply do like this,

```
   mOnClickListener = new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            //Handle onclick here
        }
    };
```

See [here](http://www.truiton.com/2015/06/android-snackbar-example/) for full example.

Answer (score 0):

I see the Kotlin way to do so is missing so I want to add my 2 cents:

```
Snackbar.make(view, "", Snackbar.LENGTH_INDEFINITE).apply {
    setAction(R.string.dismiss) { this.dismiss() }
    show()
}
```

The nice thing is the `apply` make the extra variable for dismissing the snackbar not needed

The `apply` also returns whatever its pass so you can `apply{...}.show()`